# Cell still selectable in Editing Mode

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am making a `UITableView` in editing mode with multiple selection. When it's in the editing mode and is tapped for some reason it is triggering the segue to the next page. Is there something I am missing? Doesn't triggering editing mode automatically stop the `segues`? I am triggering the segue from storyboard. I have looked all over StackOverflow. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

look at this

```
self.tableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = true
```